# Programatically create aliases for groupBy-Max function in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
var exprs = dfx.columns.map(max(_))
var df2 = df1.groupBy("x","y","z").agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*)
df2.printSchema()
```

The output of this creates a dataframe

```
root
 |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |-- y: string (nullable = true)
 |-- z: double (nullable = true)
 |-- max(a): double (nullable = true)
 |-- max(b): double (nullable = true)
 |-- max(c): double (nullable = true)
```

How does one programtically remove the max() and rename the columns with as "a" instead of max(a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
var exprs = dfx.columns.map(max(_))
```

with (and yeah, don't use `var` when `val` works fine):

```
val exprs = dfx.columns.map(c => max(c).alias(c))
```